# Не могу добавить в профиль дополнительные способы входа

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, аутентификация, user-accounts

При попытке добавить в профиль дополнительные способы входа,

на странице [ничего не происходит](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/login-add?returnUrl=%2Fusers%2Fcurrent)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
появляется страница, на которой я должен выбрать дополнительный сервис входа на сайт:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После выбора любого сервиса на странице ничего не происходит...

а хотелось бы...

Я пользуюсь Авторизацией через Google (пользуюсь только на работе).

Дома мне удобнее было бы заходить через другой сервис (ВК/facebook), но приходится все время авторизовываться в google чтобы зайти на [ru.stackoverflow.com](http://ru.stackoverflow.com)

Пробовал добавить сервис входа через браузеры:

- IE
- Firefox
- Chrome

Comment: Рекомендую использовать аккаунт StackExchange. Авторизация нужна 1 раз для каждого из сайтов сети Stack Exchange (в паре с его Метой).

Comment: @Nick Volynkin, спасибо, попробую... всё-таки это неудобствие хотелось бы устранить...  не зря же разработчики закладывали такой функционал

Comment: хм. как говорится, «у.м.в.р., ч.я.д.н.т.?». в мае ещё работало: именно тогда я **добавил** логин через *яндекс*. о.с.: *gnu*, браузер: *iceweasel* (aka *firefox*).

Comment: @alexander barakin Уже перепробовал с нескольких разных компьютеров и разных сетей (на работе... дома .. у родителей в деревне.. у девушки) везде один и тот же результат...  С мобильника (на Android 4.0.4)  получается нажать на указанные кнопки на втором скрине... проходит авторизация пишет что зайти с помощью "название сервиса"... Даже заходит! Но когда я с компьютера захожу и пытаюсь войти через сервис добавленный таким способом то ничего не происходит... не пускает

Comment: возможно, в движке что-то поломали. там какую-то единую аутентификацию приделывают – объявление ещё недавно висело.

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв! Проверил на своей учётной записи, действительно, функционал не работает. Добавил в базу дефектов. (Оказывается, [проблема](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261832/) не только у русскоязычного сообщества)